# display flash data message if session expired and redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter

If the user log on and then the session expired I get redirected to admin page OK.

But on my user library parent construct area. I would like to set flash data only if sessions expires /timed out and then redirects to admin would show flash-data message then.

So far it does not work.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->CI = & get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->library('session');
    $this->CI->load->model('admin/common/user_login_model');
    $this->CI->load->model('admin/user/users_group_model');
    $this->CI->load->model('admin/user/users_model');


    if (($this->CI->session->userdata('last_activity') + config_item('sess_expiration')) < mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())) {
    $this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('error', "Session Timed Out."); // <--added
    return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Still redirects to admin if sessions expired/ timed out but not display message.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
```

Note: This function should be the last one called, and even flash variables will no longer be available. If you only want some items destroyed and not all, use unset_userdata().